# Threading in blocks

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a list of IDs , lets say 1,000 of them.

I need to start a thread for each one with a max of 10 running at any time

I thought of using paging on a Linq result set but I would loose the running of 10 all the time.

Any suggestions on how I can keep 10 threads running at all times until all records are processed

Comment: `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach` are your friends...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using *Parallel Linq* (*PLinq*), something like this:

```
List<int> IDs = ...

IDs
  .AsParallel()
  .WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
  .ForAll(id => /*TODO: put relevant code here*/ );
```

Comment: Nailed it, that is exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you.